# WPF: Launch ModalDialog control from within XAML?

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, xaml

I'm building WPF client application. I'm following MVC pattern.

The project solution has many items, so I created „Views“  and  „Controllers“ separate assemblies.  „Views“ assembly references „Controllers“.

**Problem:** I need to load ShowModalDialog user control from withing controller instance which has no reference to View dialog control.

Is there a way to launch ModalDialog control from within XAML ?

AlbertasA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into that same problem a while ago and there wasn't a built-in solution. This is a workaround I used: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/XAMLDialog.aspx